# ASP.NET 4.0 hosting

Tags: hosting, asp.net-4.0

We have built an application on the ASP.NET 4.0 platform.  We need to go live in the next two weeks and I want to find a host that will offer the RTM of .NET 4.0.  Any ideas of any hosts that have plans to offer the newest version shortly after Monday's launch?  I see a bunch with RC1 hosting, but I can't find any hard dates for offering the RTM.

Comment: DiscountASP as of 4/14/10 now supports .Net 4.0 in production. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have a site on [DiscountASP.Net](http://discountasp.net/) and they upgraded services on 4/8 for a "soon release" of .Net 4.0.

EDIT as of 4/14/10: DiscountASP.Net now supports .Net 4.0 in production.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [orcsweb](http://www.orcsweb.com/).

They have [VS2010 and ASP.NET 4.0|RC Program - FREE Hosting](http://www.orcsweb.com/programs/visual-studio-2010-free-hosting/).

Maybe they'll have the RTM soon.

Answer (score 0):

Noone will give you hard dates - because of possible issues and the amount of work the update may require POTENTIALLY.

THat said, I would expect the known and already named players to start offering ASP.NET hosting with 4.0 ASAP. ASAP may be within days. But if you are a large host, a couple of testing days may be really - hm - justified. I personally plan to go to 4.0 ASAP (as in: as soon as I get my hands on it), but - then - I only run 2 web servers and a couple of other severs internally that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [Reliable Site](http://payments.reliablesite.net/aff.php?aff=026)  as far as I can see they will be supporting 4.0 very soon(or have it installed already).

> ASP and ASP.Net 4.0 Hosting
>
> Support for the latest .Net releases
>   including Asp.Net 1.1, 2.0, 3.5, AJAX,
>   Asp.Net 3.5 SP1, and ASP.Net 4.0.
>   Addon module support for ASP.Net MVC
>   2.0 and IIS URL Rewrite. Fully secured, and always quick.